# How do you search for keys with a value? For example get all KEYS where the value is "somevalue"

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

```
   redis> SMEMBERS CO:1:A
    1) "1"
    2) "2"

   redis> SMEMBERS CO:2:A
    1) "1"
    2) "5"
    3) "6"

   redis> SMEMBERS CO:3:A
    1) "5"

   redis> SMEMBERS CO:4:A
    1) "1"
```

Now I want to find the keys where the value  **1** exist

If I search with the values **1** then the result keys will be `CO:1:A, CO:2:A` and `CO:4:A`

How to get This?

Answer (score 6):

Redis is not a relational database.
You need to anticipate this access path, and maintain a reverse index.

```
# This is your index
SADD CO:1:A 1 2
SADD CO:2:A 1 5 6
SADD CO:3:A 5
SADD CO:4:A 1

# Here is the reverse index
SADD REV:1 1 2 4
SADD REV:2 1
SADD REV:5 2 3
SADD REV:6 2
```

Now you can query in reverse way:

```
SMEMBERS REV:1
1) "1"
2) "2"
3) "4"
... meaning CO:1:A. CO:2:A, CO:4:A
```