# Use WHERE clause in Redis to query value

Tags: redis

I am learning redis and I have a beginner question. I know that redis is all about keys! Is there any way to query/parse the value of a key for something specific?

Lets say I have keys and some json as values.
e.g.

```
key1 = {"id":"1", "colour":"red}
key2 = {"id":"2", "colour":"green}
key3 = {"id":"3", "colour":"red}
```

How do I query for all "values (jsons) that have the colour=red?

```
select all values WHERE colour==red
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you need is a **reverse index** on the `colour` field, i.e a mapping `colour -> {keyA, ..., keyB}`, e.g `"red" -> {key1, key2}`.

You can use a Redis [set](http://redis.io/commands#set) to maintain this index, as explained by [Ohm](http://ohm.keyvalue.org/#set):

> A set in Redis is an unordered list [...] It's used internally by Ohm to keep track of the instances of each model and for generating and maintaining indexes.

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810135/1688185) by Didier Spezia.

To sum up: *store data the way you will query it*.

### Ohm example

Here is what happens with Ohm behind the scenes.

First declare your Ohm model, and index the `colour` attribute since you want to query it:

```
require "ohm"

class Doc < Ohm::Model
  attribute :colour
  index :colour
end
```

Then create some docs:

```
ruby> Doc.create(:colour => "red")
ruby> Doc.create(:colour => "green")
ruby> Doc.create(:colour => "red")
```

At this step inspect what Ohm stored in the related index:

```
redis> SMEMBERS "Doc:indices:colour:red"
1) "1"
2) "3"
```

Create one more red document:

```
ruby> Doc.create(:colour => "red")
```

Re-inspect the index:

```
redis> SMEMBERS "Doc:indices:colour:red"
1) "1"
2) "3"
3) "4"
```

The index has been updated to reflect the last record.

Now you can query your documents efficiently:

```
ruby> Doc.find(:colour => "red").each {|d| puts d.id}
1
3
4
```

Comment: That means if I get another key4 = {"id":"4", "colour":"red} I would also need to update "red" -> {key1, key3, key4} ?